# webclient 400 Bad Request from POST

Tags: java, spring-boot, webclient

I use a web client for authentication to an API but I get this error. knowing that the URI is correct .
the error :
**org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from POST   with root cause**

````
 ```WebClient client = WebClient.create();
    JSONObject credentials = new JSONObject();
    credentials.put("login", "admin");
    credentials.put("password", "admin");
    String response = client.post()
            .uri(new URI("http://localhost:8080/rest/auth/v1/token:create"))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(credentials)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .block();```
````

Comment: Will be hard to help if we don't know the requirements for the endpoint.

Comment: I test the authentication with postman it works well  the requiremnts  to authentcate  client are valid login and password  for more info when i test this code using rest template  the authentication successful . but with web client i get this error